# How to remove commas from a text file?

Tags: java, buffer

I got this far, but it seems that buffer won't take arrays, because first I had it this way

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
  // Print the content on the console
 // System.out.println (strLine);
   String Record = strLine;
  String delims = "[,]";
  String[] LineItem = Record.split(delims);

  //for (int i = 0; i < LineItem.length; i++)
      for (int i = 0; i == 7; i++)
  {
    System.out.print(LineItem[i]);
  }
```

now I leave at this, because it's reading but not taking out commas.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class mainPro1test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\2010_Transactions.txt"));
            String text = null;

            // repeat until all lines is read
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String Record = text;
                String delims = "[,]";
                String[] LineItem = Record.split(delims);

                contents.append(text)
                    .append(System.getProperty(
                        "line.separator"));


            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // show file contents here       
        System.out.println(contents.toString());
    }
}
```

of how it should look like

input

```
Sell,400,IWM   ,7/6/2010,62.481125,24988.02,4.43
Sell,400,IWM   ,7/6/2010,62.51,24999.57,4.43
```

output

```
Sell    400    IWM    7/6/2010    62.481125    24988.02    4.43
Sell    400    IWM    7/6/2010    62.51        24999.57    4.43
```

Comment: Brackets to be separated from commas with some space in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to remove commas from a String, you can use `String.replaceAll(",","");`
If you want to replace them by spaces, use `String.replaceAll(","," ")`:

```
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    contents.append(text.replaceAll(","," ");
}
```

Also in your code you seem to split the input, but don't use the result of this operation.

Comment: input
Sell,400,IWM   ,7/6/2010,62.481125,24988.02,4.43
Sell,400,IWM   ,7/6/2010,62.51,24999.57,4.43
output
Sell    400    IWM    7/6/2010    62.481125    24988.02    4.43
Sell    400    IWM    7/6/2010    62.51        24999.57    4.43

Answer (score 1):

Easier is to define a new `InputStream` that just removes the commas...

```
class CommaRemovingStream extends InputStream {
  private final InputStream underlyingStream;

  // Constructor

  @Override public int read() throws IOException {
    int next;

    while (true) {
      next = underlyingStream.read();
      if (next != ',') {
        return next;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can read the file without commas:

```
InputStream noCommasStream = new CommaRemovingStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Comment: You can get rid of the first check for `next == -1`. It would get handled in the `next != ','`.